# Executing program in Windows 10 does nothing

Tags: windows-10, qt5, paraview

I build a Qt based program and when tried to run it on Windows 10 but nothing happens, and I don't know what's going on, I can't see any error.

I downloaded Clone1 from https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/tree/master/Examples%2FCustomApplications%2FClone1 and build it with CMake and Ninja. 
I then add some paths because I was getting errors:

`set PATH=C:\...\paraview\build\install\bin`
`set PATH=C:\Qt\5.9.9\msvc2015_64\bin;%PATH%`

I then tried to run it in the terminal like:

`> start paraview_clone1.exe` or `> paraview_clone1` but nothing.

Is there any way to know whats going on?

Comment: Would be nice to post the errors that you were getting before your fix.

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: which version of ParaView are you building ? and how ? Does ParaView run ?

Comment: @celmai You wrote: "I then add some paths because I was getting errors"

What errors?

Answer (score 0):

If it silently crashes, easiest way would be to just build it in debug mode and run it through a debugger.

Comment: How do I run it through a debugger?

Comment: My `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is already in `Debug` for `Clone1`. Is that what you mean with "build in debug mode"?

Comment: Yes, you have a debug build. As for the debugger - I don't know what toolchain you are using. Qt for Windows has at least (that I know of) two official builds - one for mingw and one for Visual c++. Depending on the compiler there is also a debugger. If you are using Qt Creator you can start the debugging by either pressing F5 (default shortcut) or by clicking on the bug/play-button in the sidebar in the botton left corner (it's above the hammer button). Don't remember how it's in Visual Studio.

Comment: If you like the command line you need to either give the absolute path to your debugger (for mingw it's gdb) or add it to PATH and pass your application's binary as argument. Additional arguments are available but for starters this should do.